# Get Display Brightness

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks

Is there a way to get the display brightness in OS X 10.9+ now that `CGDisplayIOServicePort` has been deprecated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some searching and fiddling around, here is a "future proof" way to get the brightness of the display that doesn't use the CGDisplayIOServicePort deprecated in OS X 10.9.

```
- (float)getDisplayBrightness
{
    float brightness = 1.0f;
    io_iterator_t iterator;
    kern_return_t result = 
        IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,
            IOServiceMatching("IODisplayConnect"),
            &iterator);

    // If we were successful
    if (result == kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
        io_object_t service;

        while ((service = IOIteratorNext(iterator)))
        {
            IODisplayGetFloatParameter(service, 
                kNilOptions, 
                CFSTR(kIODisplayBrightnessKey), 
                &brightness);

            // Let the object go
            IOObjectRelease(service);
        }
    }

    return brightness;
}
```

Comment: Can we control an external display brightness using this service ? Does this have any relation with the DDC/Ci commands ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift the following should work:

```
func getDisplayBrightness() -> Float {

    var brightness: Float = 1.0
    var service: io_object_t = 1
    var iterator: io_iterator_t = 0
    let result: kern_return_t = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IODisplayConnect"), &iterator)

    if result == kIOReturnSuccess {

        while service != 0 {
            service = IOIteratorNext(iterator)
            IODisplayGetFloatParameter(service, 0, kIODisplayBrightnessKey as CFString, &brightness)
            IOObjectRelease(service)
        }
    }
    return brightness
}
```

Comment: Works only on Intel processor do you know how to get current brightness level on ARM (Apple Silicone)?

Comment: @AviRok Haven't tried it on the new macs yet. Did you try making a Universal app, or one that runs specifically on only Mac? In case of the Universal app not surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried it on macOS only app in M1 Pro MacBook (works on Intel). As I know we can use DisplayService private framework to get and set level brightness on Apple silicone but I don't know how do to it :)

Comment: Looking at the documentation it seems like most of this has finally been deprecated (quartz is a relic of the objective-c days and I never liked it): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgdisplaystream/1455170-init?changes=latest_minor that being said you would need to look around and find out what they replaced it with (maybe they made a WWDC video about it) or google arround a bit.

Comment: I’m trying to get brightness with private framework DisplayServices if I got I will share the answer, If you found a better way please post it

Comment: Are you using UIKit by any chance? If so using this is probably best: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617830-brightness

Comment: I don’t use UIKIt because my app is macOS only (not universal) is it possible to use UIKit without universal app?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I get brightness level of Apple Silicone (tested on M1 Pro) by using private framework DisplayServices.framework `extern int DisplayServicesGetBrightness(CGDirectDisplayID display, float *brightness);`  you just need to find the DisplayServices header file

*I'm not tested it with external display yet

```
func getDisplayBrightnessM1() -> Float {
var brightness: Float = 0.0
DisplayServicesGetBrightness(1, &brightness)
return brightness
}
```